# Calculating line integral : disk

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

It is given: $c\in \mathbb C, r>0, z_0\notin \partial K_r(c)$ and $n \in \mathbb Z.$

Claculate $\int_{\partial K_r(c)}^{} \! (z-z_0)^{n} \, dz$.

Can someone give me some hint and tell me how to start?

P.S. $\partial K_r(c)$ is a disk (i.e. circle plus its interior) of radius $r$ centered at $c$.

Comment: Isn't this just zero since we have the integral of a holomorphic function (polynom), over a closed curve? You have no singularities in your disk should be zero.

Answer (score 0):

For $n \ne -1$ the integral $=0$, since  $(z-z_0)^n $ has an antiderivative

A direct calculation with the definition of a line integral shows that for  $n = -1$ the integral = $2 \pi i $